# Filter users from cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I need to list users from Cognito user pool, filter by given_name and by their user pool group.

Attempted solutions:

- Tried using **listUsersInGroup** function from AWS SDK, but cannot filter by given_name.
- Tried using **listUsers** function, can filter by given_name but cannot filter by group.

*Note:* Could have used JavaScript array methods to filter, but it doesn't scale.

what could be the solution for this?

Comment: Cognito is not the best tool for filtering users